# SQL Server Dynamic table From field names stored in database

Tags: sql-server

Can I create table with field names coming from the database? I have a table called "field_names" and that decides which column name should be there in a table. Based on results from that table, I need to create a table in a database using those fields.

Comment: I would urge you to read this question and ask yourself if you think you could possibly provide an answer based on what you posted. As it sits right now it is so vague I don't even have a direction to guess as to what you might be looking for.

Comment: @Sean Lange which question you are mentioning?

Comment: You will have to build the CREATE TABLE statement using code (a stored procedure, vbscript, python, what-have-you) and then have it submit that dynamically generated DDL to the database. This is commonly referred to as "Dynamic SQL". Also this sounds like you are wading into an DBMS anti-pattern where you have a database defined in your database... but there are plenty of legit reasons for doing this too.

Comment: And how would you know the datatypes for said columns?

Comment: @scsimon Data types are all int

Comment: With that information @AndyJohnson, the solution below will work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this... though I think the whole concept is a terrible idea

```
declare @columnNames table (id int identity(1,1), cname varchar(256))

insert into @columnNames
values
('Column1')
,('AnotherColumn')
,('Third Column')


declare @i int = 1
declare @max_i int = (select max(id) from @columnNames)
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'create table #someNewTable( '

while @i <= @max_i
begin
    set @sql = @sql + (select QUOTENAME(cname) from @columnNames where id = @i) + ' int, '
    set @i = @i + 1
end

set @sql = left(@sql,len(@sql) - 1) + ')'
print @sql
--exec(@sql)
```

Note, you'd need to add in any constraints and indexes as well...